# SQL Server : trying to flatten a "matrix" into a row

Tags: sql-server, row, type-conversion

I have a "matrix" of Y and N see image below, what Id lile is the image below that where it is flattened into 1 row for each SID showing all the Y s on one line and the Ns like I was ORing the data in the rows. Can I do that in SQL Server?

[image]

[image]

here is my original query

```
SELECT  TERM_SID,
  CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Public data' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS 'PUBLIC',
  CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Public data in aggregate' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'PUBLIC_AGGREGATE',
  CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Internal data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'INTERNAL',
  CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Internal data in aggregate' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'INTERNAL_AGGREGATE',
  CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Limited data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'LIMITED',
  CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Restricted data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'RESTRICTED'
  FROM [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION] d2
  JOIN [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING] dm2 ON dm2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID=d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID order by TERM_SID
```

and how I was trying to sum the individual columns after converting 'Y'=1 'N'=0

```
select * from
      (
      SELECT  TERM_SID,
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Public data' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'PUBLIC',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Public data in aggregate' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as 'PUBLIC_AGGREGATE',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Internal data' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as 'INTERNAL',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Internal data in aggregate' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as 'INTERNAL_AGGREGATE',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Limited data' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as 'LIMITED',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Restricted data' THEN 1  ELSE 0 END as 'RESTRICTED'
      FROM [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION] d2
      JOIN [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING] dm2 ON dm2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID=d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID 
      ) x
      PIVOT
      (sum (x.PUBLIC) for TERM_SID in (*)) as piv
```

but I get an error at x.PUBLIC see image below

[image]

Thanks to SqlZim here is what I came up with

```
select TERM_SID
,max(PUBLICDATA) as PublicData
,max(PUBLIC_AGGREGATE) as Public_AGGregate
,max(INTERNAL) as Internal
,max(INTERNAL_AGGREGATE) as internal_Aggregate
,max(LIMITED) as Limited
,max(RESTRICTED) as Restricted
from
(
      SELECT  TERM_SID,
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Public data' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS 'PUBLICDATA',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Public data in aggregate' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'PUBLIC_AGGREGATE',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Internal data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'INTERNAL',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Internal data in aggregate' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'INTERNAL_AGGREGATE',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Limited data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'LIMITED',
      CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC='Restricted data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as 'RESTRICTED'
      FROM [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION] d2
      JOIN [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING] dm2 ON dm2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID=d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID
) mat
group by Term_SID
```

also this works using the CTE format suggested

```
with mat  (TERM_SID,PUBLICDATA,PUBLIC_AGGREGATE,INTERNAL,INTERNAL_AGGREGATE,LIMITED,RESTRICTED)
as
(
      SELECT  dm2.TERM_SID
             ,CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC = 'Public data' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PUBLICDATA
             ,CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC = 'Public data in aggregate' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as PUBLIC_AGGREGATE
             ,CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC = 'Internal data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as INTERNAL
             ,CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC = 'Internal data in aggregate' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as INTERNAL_AGGREGATE
             ,CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC = 'Limited data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as LIMITED
             ,CASE WHEN d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_DESC = 'Restricted data' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as RESTRICTED
      FROM [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION] d2
          JOIN [UDW_DATA_DICTIONARY].[dbo].[DATA_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING] dm2
              ON dm2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID = d2.DATA_CLASSIFICATION_SID
)
select m1.TERM_SID
      ,max(m1.PUBLICDATA) as PublicData
      ,max(m1.PUBLIC_AGGREGATE) as Public_AGGregate
      ,max(m1.INTERNAL) as Internal
      ,max(m1.INTERNAL_AGGREGATE) as internal_Aggregate
      ,max(m1.LIMITED) as Limited
      ,max(m1.RESTRICTED) as Restricted
      ,count(1) as mat2count
from mat m1
    left join mat m2
        on(m1.TERM_SID = m2.TERM_SID)
group by m1.Term_SID
```

Comment: What have you researched and tried before posting here?

Comment: I tried using pivot and converting the 'Y' and 'N' to 0 and 1 ...stull working on that hoping there is a way to OR them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on with the two rows for `Term_SID=3` in your second image, but this will get your closer:

```
;with mat as (
  select  
      term_sid
    , [Public] = case 
        when d2.data_classification_desc='Public data'
          then 'Y' else 'N' end
    , [Public_Aggregate] = case 
        when d2.data_classification_desc='Public data in aggregate'
          then 'Y'  else 'N' end
    , [Internal] = case 
        when d2.data_classification_desc='Internal data' 
          then 'Y'  else 'N' end
    , [Internal_Aggregate] = case 
        when d2.data_classification_desc='Internal data in aggregate'
          then 'Y'  else 'N' end
    , [Limited] = case 
        when d2.data_classification_desc='Limited data'
          then 'Y'  else 'N' end
    , [Restricted] = case 
        when d2.data_classification_desc='Restricted data' 
          then 'Y'  else 'N' end 
    from [udw_data_dictionary].[dbo].[data_classification] d2
      join [udw_data_dictionary].[dbo].[data_classification_mapping] dm2 
        on dm2.data_classification_sid=d2.data_classification_sid 
)

select
      Term_SID
    , Public             = max(Public)
    , Public_Aggregate   = max(Public_Aggregate)
    , Internal           = max(Internal)
    , Internal_Aggregate = max(Internal_Aggregate)
    , Limited            = max(Limited)
    , Restricted         = max(Restricted)
  from mat
  group by Term_SID
  order by term_sid
```